# Global variable has different memory alignment in different threads

Tags: variables, memory, alignment, global

I recently had a memory alignment issue which crashed my application and finally found one global variable has different alignment in different threads. The global variable is defined as

```
typedef struct
{
    double e1;        
    double e2;
    double e3;
    double e4;
    double e5;
    double e6;
    double e7;
    double e8;
    double e9;
    unsigned long       e10; 
    unsigned long       e11;  
    float               e12;         
} event_t;
```

It is declared in main.c

```
event_t    report[3];
```

and accessed by two threads(two files) t1 and t2. t1 is kind of producer and initializes and fills data into report. t2 just reads the data out for format conversion. In t2, the contents of report[1] are always wrong. By checking the address of report[1], I found report[1] has 4 bytes offset between t1 and t2. So I changed the definition to :

```
typedef struct
{
    double e1;        
    double e2;
    double e3;
    double e4;
    double e5;
    double e6;
    double e7;
    double e8;
    double e9;
    unsigned long       e10; 
    unsigned long       e11;  
    float               e12;         
} __attribute__ ((packed)) event_t;
```

Now both t1 and t2 are correct. t1 and t2 use mutex lock to access the global variable for synchronization. My question is why t1 is always correct but t2 has different memory alignment for this global variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Platform? 8,16,32 or 64 bit compiler? compiler?

Comment: It is 32 bit PowerPC platform (big endian) and gcc 4.1.2. The toolchain is quite old but it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: How do you know it's not relevant? Have you tried with a newer toolchain on the same platform?

Comment: After I tried a demo multi-thread case with the same toolchain and I couldn't reproduce the problem. It is my code causing the alignment issue.